# Why take().get() in ExecutorCompletionService in asynchronous tasks is taking a lot of time to 'take() result out of its first completed thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, completion-service

I have used ExecutorCompletionService to call a web service. The web service that threads are hitting returns response in 5 seconds. But, completionService.take().get() is taking almost 30 seconds to retrieve results from its very first completed thread; whereas completionService.take().get() take 6 seconds to retrieve the results from other completed threads.

I am aware about the ExecutorCompletionService that it take().get() a task that is completed first and not the one which is submitted first. But I am not able to figure out why it is taking so much time (30 sec+) to get results out of the first completed thread. 
And why not others threads, which claim in console that they took 6 seconds to complete, are not taken by take().get() to process first than the thread taking 30+ Sec.

Initially I began using ExecutorService only with Future, but then I switched to ExecutorCompletionService to get better response time. But response time does not change.
Apart from my main code, have also tried adding the tasks in Future with ExecutorCompletionService, but nothing changed:

```
CompletionService executorCompletionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executorService);
    List<Future<List<Students>>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Students>>();
    for(..)
        {
        future.add(mytasks);
        }

    for(
    int i = 0;i<futures.size();i++)
    {
        List<Students> result = executorCompletionService.take().get();
        // Some processing here
    }

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4, new ThreadFactory("myThreads"));

    CompletionService<List<Students>> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executorService);for(
    int i = 0;i<4;i++)
    {

        int thread = i;
        completionService.submit(new Callable<List<Students>>() {
            public List<Students> call() throws Exception {
                List myList = (List<Students>) anotherApi.seviceCall(Object);
                Students st = new Students();
                st.setId(thread);
                st.setName1("I am thread-----");
                myList.add(st);
                return list;
            }
        });
    }

    for(
    int i = 0;i<4;i++)
    {
        long startTimeOfReadingThread = System.currentTimeMillis(); // start
                                                                    // time of
                                                                    // reading
                                                                    // result
                                                                    // set of
                                                                    // thread
        List<Students> students = completionService.take().get();
        for (Students c : student) {
            if (c.getName() != null && c.getName() != "" && c.getName1().equals("I am thread-----"))
                System.out.println("I am thread-----" + c.getId());
        }

        long endTimeOfReadingThread = System.currentTimeMillis(); // end time
                                                                    // when
                                                                    // result
                                                                    // set of
                                                                    // thread is
                                                                    // read

        System.out.println(
                "time in threads&&&&&&&&*****" + ((endTimeOfReadingThread - startTimeOfReadingThread) / 1000F));

        response.addAll(students);
    }executorService.shutdown();
```

Response Time from system out console in seconds:

```
I am thread-----3
time in threads&&&&&&&&*****29.703
I am thread-----0
time in threads&&&&&&&&*****7.987
I am thread-----1
time in threads&&&&&&&&*****6.001
I am thread-----2
time in threads&&&&&&&&*****6.563
```

Please help me in correcting anything that I am doing wrong. I only know is, if 4 threads are going in parallel using Executor Completion Service and another service being hit is not taking more than 5-6 seconds for one thread, then my first completed thread should not take more than 6-7 seconds (just like other threads).

This is leading to total response time to user is almost 33 seconds.

Comment: Do you see the same timing if you `call()` the same set of tasks synchronously instead of via a `CompletionService`?  Similarly, how do you know that the web service is actually returning the first result in five seconds?

Comment: 1. Yes, synchronous tasks also return complete response in same time, thus I shifted to ExecutorService and then to CompletionService.
2. I have taken a random request from one of the threads going to another web service directly using postman tool and it returned response in 6-7 seconds. Infact, multiple hits from postman to this web service is bringing response in 6-7 seconds only.

Comment: Since you see the same timing when running the tasks synchronously the issue must reside in `anotherApi.seviceCall()` [sic] or the web service behind it, not in the `ExecutorService` or `CompletionService`.  We don't have enough information to answer such a question.

Comment: Ok. Did you see any problem in the code that I have written to process CompletionService?

Comment: I do not recognize any problems inherent in the way you use the `CompletionService`.  I do note, however, that the timings you show are all measured by the same thread, *sequentially*.  Thus, although you submit all the tasks to the `CompletionService` at about the same time, and the first to complete does so 30 seconds later, the second to complete does so 30s + 8s = 38s after its submission, and the next six seconds after that, *etc*..  That presents the appearance that they are being serialized somewhere, despite running in separate threads.